# Threejs Shader - gl_FragColor with Alpha (opacity not changing)

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm trying to write a simple shader where half of my scene will be displayed and half of the scene will be transparent.  I can't seem to figure out why the transparency isn't working:

```
  uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main(){
        vec2 p = vUv;
        vec4 color;      

        if(p.x < 0.5){ 
              color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }else{
              color = texture2D(tDiffuse, p);
        }

        gl_FragColor = color;
  }
```

The shader is definitely running without errors - the right half of the screen is my threejs scene and the left half of the screen is red (when it should really be transparent).  I've read that maybe I need to call glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA); - but I am getting errors when I try this.  To do this I did renderer.context.blendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA); in my main js file (not the shader).  Am I supposed to place this somewhere else to make it work?

Any help would be appreciated.  For reference I'm applying my shader with the standard effectsComposer, shaderPass, etc - which most threejs shader examples use.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to help you with only partial information and code snippets, so I can only make educated guesses.

By default `EffectComposer` uses a render target with `RGB` format. Did specify `RGBA`?

Did you specify material.transparent = true?

three.js r.56

Comment: WestLangley - sorry for not providing the full code - here it is (http://108.171.176.74/~rtilton1/stackOverflow/).  Thanks also for clarifying the EffectComposer defaults as RGB format rather than RGBA.  I guess I'm not understanding where to access the material with the effects composer since I can't do 'composer.transparent = true;'

Comment: In your case, it would be `window.effect.material.transparent = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and for me it was that the material didn't have transparency enabled.

```
let myMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: myUniforms,
  fragmentShader: myFragmentShader(),
  vertexShader: myVertexShader(),
});
myMaterial.transparent = true;
```