# Alpha color with ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to write a shader material for displaying THREE.Points() objects with rounded points. I am doing this by controlling the alpha value in a fragment shader.

Below is a fully working version of my code. I am getting the desired effect of only colouring pixels within the circle. Outside, however, I am getting white instead of the background colour.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285287/threejs-shader-gl-fragcolor-with-alpha-opacity-not-changing) is related to mine. I tried setting `material.transparent = true` but it did not have any effect.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>THREEJS alpha shader</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Shaders -->
        <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
            void main() {
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
                gl_PointSize = 40.0; // pixels
            }
        </script>

        <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
            varying vec4 color;

            void main() {
                // radius
                float r = length(gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5, 0.5));

                if(r < 0.5) {
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                } else {
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var buffer = new Float32Array(3);   // single point located at (0, 0, 0)
            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
            geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(buffer,3) );

            // create shader material
            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                vertexShader : $('#vertexshader').text(),
                fragmentShader : $('#fragmentshader').text(),
                });

            var point = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
            scene.add(point);
            camera.position.z = 2;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your accepted answer is not how to do it in three.js. Instead of setting alpha to zero, do this: `if ( length( gl_PointCoord - vec2( 0.5, 0.5 ) ) > 0.475 ) discard;`

Comment: The accepted answer solved the problem of enabling alpha blending for ShaderMaterial. However, your code helped me to eliminate a strange rendering in the corners. Thanks.

Comment: You enable alpha blending in three.js by setting material.transparent = true;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable alpha blending within the OpenGL context. I am not sure if there is a way to do this using three.js, but adding these GL commands to your render() function will suffice:

```
var render = function () {
  var gl = renderer.context;
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

See the MDN docs on [blendFunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc) for a bit more information on this.